# Form is submitting even condition fails (MVC3)

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery and MVC to do form submission like this

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Orders", "Customers", new AjaxOptions() {
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId =
 updatemessages" }, new { id = "formupdate" })) {
       <input type="submit" class="t-button" id="btnupdate" value="Update Orders"/>  
}

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnupdate').live("click", function () {
         return false;
    ); 
  });
 </script>
```

I am doing Form POST HERE.

**I'M CHECKING FORM VALIDATIONS IN SUBMIT BUTTON function, if validation fails, I don't want to do form POST , IF SUCCESS ,DO FORM POST**

```
$('#btnupdate').live("click", function () {

  if(success) {

  // do form POST <BR/>
}

else
{
// dont do form POST <BR/>

}
```

### - **Actually ,can I do like this**

```
$("form#theForm").submit(function(evt){

    $('#btnupdate').live("click", function () {

if(success) {

// do form POST 
}

else {

evt.preventDefault(); // dont do form POST 

}
  });
```

Comment: Please tell us what your goal is and why it is failing, or any error messages

Comment: Is there a reason your targeting the "click" of a submit instead of the "submit" of the form? What version of jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">  </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
        $('#btnupdate').live("click", function () {
            if (!$("#formupdate").valid()) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        //Or

        $("form#formupdate").live('submit', function () {
            if (!$(this).valid()) {
                return false;
            }
        });
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: It worked for me this way ,** $("form#formupdate").submit(function () {  if(!success){return false;}}**

Comment: I still would change it from button click to form submit incase "enter" is used and I would make use of the preventDefault: $('#formupdate').live("submit", function (e) { if (!$(this).valid()) { e.preventDefault(); }});

Comment: @ThulasiRam, code is not working in IE, working fine in Firefox  $("form#formupdate").live('submit', function () {
            return false;
        });   .

Comment: try this. u call that above two js script. IE version?

Comment: for me also same problem was there before. i tryed with this it is working fine in IE 9.1